# How to update views simultaneously in android

Tags: android, android-view

I am developing an android application for API level 10 (2.3.3). In my application, one seek bar is available which has values from 0-25.

My problem is when I progress on seekbar, I am updating multiple views. As view can be updated from UI thread only, all the views update synchronously means one by one. Means I can see that view is updating. My updates doesn't require any background work.

So my question is Is there any way to update the views simultaneously? Means for example if I have 15 views, can I update all at the same time like by spanning some thread?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share some code of what you did already please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible.

Let's consider that you actually could update UI components from outside the UI thread (which you can't), even that wouldn't be simultaneous.

Let's say thread 1 makes 100 operations **t1o1**, **t1o2**, ..., **t1o100** and thread 2 makes *t2o1*, *t2o2*, ..., *t2o100*.

If you run both of them they will be executed in an order similar to:

**t1o1**

*t2o1*

**t1o2**

**t1o3**

*t2o2*

....

Both threads are running simultaneously but no 2 operations are being executed at the same time.

Comment: I can see asynctask can be run in parallel but its not available in api level 10. Similar to that functionality I want. Means I dont want to depend/halt on one view when it is updating.

Comment: Asynctask *is* available in api level 10. But that's not the point. You might have misunderstood my answer. No 2 views can be updated at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, updates can only be done from UI thread, and the UI Thread can handle only one view by one. So you have no choice but doing updating them one by one. But if you put all updates into one runnable, you normally shouldn't see the process of updating.

Comment: so you are invoking the updates from the UI Thread? what are you doing to calculate the values?

Answer (score 0):

not sure asking about this but AsyncTask and doInBackground works for this. also when a background task done you can update your seek bar from onPostExecute. but you need carry the context which has the seek bar.

Comment: As I said, I am not doing any background work. So no use of async task.